# Function returns the same value many times I Python

Tags: python, function, return

I need to write a function that will convert the number A to base N. In this case, the number 19 is binary. All I have to do is rewrite the resulting number backwards and return from the function.
I looked into debug mode and didn't understood a thing honestly, it's just looping over line 15 because of... reasons I guess.

```
def translate(a, n=2):
    r1 = []
    r2 = ()
    r3 = ()

    b = int(a/n)
    c = a%n
    
    if b >= 1:
        r1.append(str(c))
        r1.append(str(translate(b,n)))
    else:
        r1.append(str(c))
    
    return r1

print(translate(19,2))
```

I didn’t manage to come up with much, after all, I’m not a programmer at all, but I need to do this so that I don’t get expelled.

[image]

Comment: `if b >= 1:` should probably be `if b >= n:`

Comment: Could you please copy-paste your debugger output instead of posting a screenshot? It's far more readable. Also, it seems that there are useless variables in your example. If you try making a minimal example, debugging is going to be easier.

Comment: @BlackBeans, i'm honestly not sure what I'm should copy-paste. U can see on the screenshot that "return r1" was called at least ten times. I think u can just copy my code and try to step-by-step debug it on spyder or conda ide.

Comment: Basically, you should avoid to post text as an image. If something could be either copy-pasted or screenshoted, it should be copy-pasted (in this case, you should copy-paste the whole pdb session to show what you did). Of course, I could do it on my own, but the goal is to make it easy for other people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that every time you call the function, it would append to the list and also, the list would be initialized every time it was called. Hence using a global variable and instead of appending the returned value in the if block just running the function again worked. Code:

```
r1 = []
def translate(a, n=2):
    global r1
    r2 = ()
    r3 = ()

    b = int(a/n)
    c = a%n
    
    if b >= 1:
        r1.append(str(c))
        # print(r1)
        translate(b,n)
        # print(r1)
    else:
        r1.append(str(c))
    
    # return r1
translate(2,2)
print(''.join(r1)[::-1])# Join and reverse
```

Comment: I tried to use a global variable, but it didn't change anything, so even mentioning it flew out of my head.
In your version, the same problem on debugging, but the line with the reverse at least allows me to get an answer and complete the task, thanks.
But I'm still wondering where it comes from.
In the debugger of the spider, at some point it is clear that additional files are being opened (iostream.py and socket.py) from which the code is being processed, but I am too bad at programming to make out something there.

Comment: @LuciBezier make sure you change the `r1.append(str(translate(b,n)))` to `translate(b,n)`. Also, I couldn't completely understand your statement. Could you please simplify it a little?

Comment: I think I could make a video, English's not my first language so it's kinda hard for me to speak on it
Wait a bit, please

Comment: https://youtu.be/qjUulVhUFy8

Comment: As far as the `iostream.py` is concerned, it is a file that tells Spyder how to print things. Reference: [Python:Debugging](https://pundit.pratt.duke.edu/wiki/Python:Debugging), So it's pretty much unrelated. I have no idea about `socket.py` either

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a recursive approach for this. Here's a technique that will work for where 2 <= base <= 10 and a >= 0

```
def translate(a, base=2):
    r = ''
    while a > 0:
        r += str(a % base)
        a //= base
    return r[::-1] if r else '0'
```

Comment: Looks beautiful, thanks